# Linking Url is not cleared

Tags: react-native, deep-linking, react-native-deep-linking

Am working on deep linking, I integrated Linking and created deep link. Its worked fine but when i click back button then page redirect to previous screen and suddenly it redirect to chat page am not able to clear the URL when i come back.

```
componentDidMount() {
       Linking.getInitialURL().then(url => {
            this.navigate(url);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.warn(">>>>>>>>>err", err)
        });
        Linking.addEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL);
      }
    componentWillUnmount() {
   
    Linking.removeEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL);
  
   }

handleOpenURL = (event) => {
    this.navigate(event.url);
}
navigate = (url) => {
    if (url === "appchat://chat/") {
       //when i comeback url hit here and page redirected automatically 
        this.props.navigation.navigate('chat')
    } else {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('dashboard')
    }

}
```